# What is the right way for a reducer to affect state that is far away?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am building a React-Redux project and I am trying to be idiomatic about my usage of Redux, and avoid hacking things together in a way that makes the code difficult to maintain later. I am also new to this ecosystem.

I have a nested state that looks something like this:

```
{ foo: {stuff}, bar: {baz: {stuff} } }
```

and I use `combineReducers`, so that `foo` and `bar` and `baz` all have their own reducers to interpret relevant actions for changing their own state. But I've run into a situation where an action could, depending on the state of `baz`, have an implication that might be of interest to `foo`.

I have basically three ideas, where I hate the first one and don't know how to do the other two:

1) Make the reducers for bar/baz have access to the whole state, and ask them to be responsible about it.

This makes this exact situation easy to deal with, but it seems bad from a  separation of concerns perspective.

2) Somehow have the `baz` reducer dispatch a relevant action that `foo` would then pick up on.

This makes sense to me from a descriptiveness perspective, but I don't actually know how to do it. The fact that it's not obvious makes me think Redux is against this.

3) Import some magic library that makes this simple

I don't know what library would do this, though. It doesn't seem like this is what redux-thunk does (although I'm not sure) and then I really don't know.

Comment: Please see the [Redux FAQ entry on sharing state between reducers](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you keep your reducers simple. They are there to modify the slice of state they care for, and nothing else.

If an "action" affects more than one slice, then it should dispatch multiple, "actions".. The naming can get confusing at this point, but basically `redux-thunk` allows you to do just this.

If you have regular action creators, eg `modifyFoo` & `modifyBar` which simply return action objects which are dispatched to the reducers, with `redux-thunk` enabled you can create a more complex "action" which dispatches both. eg..

```
function modifyFoo(options) {
  return { type: "MODIFY_FOO", payload: options }};
}

function modifyBar(options) {
  return { type: "MODIFY_BAR", payload: options }};
}

function modifyFooBar(options) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const appState = getState();
    dispatch(modifyFoo(options.foo, appState.baz));
    dispatch(modifyBar(options.bar));
  }
}
```

Using `getState` you have access to the full state of the app if you need it.

Comment: The problem is whether the second action kicks off, depends on the state relevant to the first action, _after_ that action has been processed. (e.g., if the action causes a counter to drop below zero in baz, then send a message over to foo). It is inherently sequential!

Comment: mm.. sounds like a computed property which isn't the recommended way to go. Whatever relies on the value in foo should probably be reading the value direct from baz. You might want a selector, eg `isBelowZero` which reads baz and returns a boolean.

Comment: I don't think this situation is really a computed property situation; it's more of a "if this thing with the state happens, trigger something else." I don't think redux-thunk is a good fit for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr -- I've decided to use `redux-loop`, which lets you describe side effects of a reducer without making the reducer pure/stateless.

**Why I did not use `redux-thunk` for this:**

The most common approach (based on my googling), represented in @lecstor's answer, is to use `redux-thunk`. In the typical `redux-thunk` code organization, you have to figure out everything that's going to happen first, then dispatch some numbers of actions, async operations, etc. through a thunk.

The downside in this case is the second action is (a) conditional on the state *after* the first action triggers, and (b) cannot be derived from the state itself, but must be derived from the fact that we have this state *after* this action.

So with `redux-thunk` you either have to duplicate the logic of the reducer (bad), or do all the business logic before the reducers, then launching a bunch of actions that describe state changes.

This is all to say, `redux-thunk` does its magic *before* the reducer happens.

**Why I think `redux-loop` was a better fit:**

On the other hand, `redux-loop` does magic *after* the reducer happens, allowing the reducer to describe those effects (including kicking off async actions, dispatching further actions, etc.) without breaking statelessness.

For the historical record, this means that in the `foo` reducer above you can do:

```
// ... nextState is the new fooState
if (isWeird(nextState)) {
  return loop(nextState, Cmd.action(makeWeirdAction()));
} else {
  return nextState;
}
```

so that all other reducers can interpret or ignore weird action as they please, instead of making these decisions all at once in the action creator.